# Design pattern choice for a service (or something else) with heavy reliance on current context

Tags: design-patterns, service, dependency-injection, factory

I have a service (not a remote one) which deals with simple requests, many of which will actually be for the same segment of data. That segment gets loaded many times during a given activity because the service can't reliably collate the requests and query the data only the once. The data isn't a good fit for caching, so I don't think caching is the right choice.

I wish to avoid passing in a context to each method, and would prefer this to belong to the instance of the service I'm using (understanding it would no longer be a service.) I'm imagining using a factory to create the object while passing in the details I need.

What pattern can I use?

Comment: I've started working on this and have tentatively renamed the service as a provider, and created a factory to make them, taking in the context data and lazy loading resources for that single object.

Comment: Do you aim at improving performance or expressing in code a common abstraction for similar requests ? What exactly do you mean by "current context" ? You might want to be more specific and concrete here.

Comment: I'm not aiming for performance but I think the fact that I load the same data repeatedly points to an architectural flaw. Current context means that a thread will be working on a specific subset of data, through the service, and that the service should know of this and be able to load it up only the once. Service is probably the wrong pattern, so the core of the question is what pattern would be best for this type of thing?

Comment: I might not completely get your point, but I fail to see how this could not boil down to caching. You can cache data at various levels in multiple ways, including ones that make cache invalidation and refresh transparent to the consumer, but "load the same data repeatedly" basically screams caching, IMO.

Comment: I think cache here would be a plaster. The real problem ended up being my architecture. I moved a few things around and loaded the entire graph of objects required for a single operation in a dictionary of lazy objects. As the intention for this class is to exist one per thread in a web context, that's working fine. It still takes a little while to do but, considering the amount of tables involved, acceptable. I don't think there's really a pattern for what I was asking.

Comment: Voted to close my own question as I'm not sure I knew what I was asking for at the time.